# Change weight painting Colors?

Tags: weight-painting

I'm red green colorblind and I'm having difficulty with weight painting as a lot of the colors involve bleed into each other.

I did some searching around but couldn't find anything so is there a way to change the color scheme that weight painting uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using 2.79: You need to go to File >> USer Preferences >> System >> Custom Weight Paint Range

If you are using 2.80: You need to go to Edit >> Preferences >> Editing >>Weight Paint >> Use custom colors.

[image]

Hope that helps
Good Luck

Comment: Thank you, now i just need to find a balance and a set of colors that works.